# Change font sizes of a QFileDialog in QT

Tags: android, qt

I am developing an app on android platform using QT. When I am using the FileDialog of the app to open a file on the mobile phone, I find the font size is too small for my finger to select a folder. How can I make the font size larger?

I tried the following code, but the font size doesn't change.

```
this->setStyleSheet("QTreeView {font: 40pt \"Arial\";}");
QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(NULL,"","/mnt/sdcard/test/");
```

My code is finally changed to this, but the font still doesn't change:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QFileDialog *fdiag = new QFileDialog;
    fdiag->setStyleSheet("QTreeView {font: 40pt \"Arial\";}"); //    QFileDialog

//    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,"","/mnt/sdcard/test/",QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
    QString dir = fdiag->getExistingDirectory(this,QString(),"/mnt/sdcard/test/",QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

    model = new QFileSystemModel();
    filesPath = dir;
    model->setRootPath(dir);
```

Comment: Offtopic: don't use widgets, they has bad design for mobile platforms. Use QML/QtQuick.

Comment: If you want to increase the font size of all widgets in the filedialog's, try the following: `this->setStyleSheet("QFileDialog QWidget {font: 40pt;}");`

Comment: Thank you. It works now! :)